# Как в woocomerce вывести массив из id и min_price для каталога товаров?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите как получить список id, min_price всех товаров что сейчас выводятся на странице? Хочу вывести такой результат:

```
'ecomm_prodid': [9847,8942,8923,8904,8885,8866,8847,8828,8809,8790,8771,8752, 8729,8707,8651,7527,7508,7489]
'ecomm_totalvalue': '120.00, 125.00, 110.00, 120.00, 120.00, 120.00, 120.00, 120.00, 120.00, 120.00, 120.00, 120.00]'
```

где ecomm_prodid (8942...) - список товаров что выводятся на странице а ecomm_totalvalue (125.00...) цены товаров, и соответственно id 8942 c min_price = 125.00.

Уже третий день пытаюсь получить список id и никак не могу это сделать, почему-то даже на странице каталога где выводятся 20 товаров, когда я пишу такой код, то получаю только один товар - он идет самым первым.

```
//если написать так - получаем цену, но только первого товара на странице
echo $product->id;

$product = get_product( $post->ID );

        if(is_object($product))
            // цена также выводится
            $price = $product->get_price();
          else
            $price = $product;
```

Помогите куда копать, я пришел в WP с Joomla и не понимаю некоторых вещей. Мне не понятно почему в $product нет массива всех товаров с массивом цен.
Нужно мне это для вывода кода для Google ремаркетинга, который должен выглядить так

```
<script>
gtag('event', 'page_view', {
   'send_to': ['UA-XXXXXXXX-1','AW-XXXXXXXXXXX]', 
   'ecomm_prodid': [9847,8942,8923,8904,8885],
   'ecomm_pagetype': 'catalog',
   'ecomm_totalvalue': '100.00,120.00,125.00,112.00,105.00'           
});

</script">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы получить все товары можно воспользоваться функцией [wc_get_products](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)

Далее через цикл получить id и цену. Пример при условии что товары не вариативные:

```
        $products = wc_get_products(array(
            'numberposts' => -1, // все товары
            'post_status' => 'published', // только опубликованные
        ) );

        $products_total = [];
        $products_total['id'] = [];
        $products_total['price'] = [];
        /**@var WC_Product $product*/
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            array_push($products_total['id'],$product->get_id());
            array_push($products_total['price'],$product->get_price());
        }
        var_dump($products_total);
```

Comment: Алексей спасибо, но товары как раз все вариативные, и код не работает. Если я его конечно правильно исполняю - я делаю вызов через function.php. В массиве у меня ```/Users/ut4utc/PRJ/Parquet/Sites/parketdoska-v2.loc/wp-content/themes/woodheart-child/functions.php:500:
array (size=2)
  'id' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'price' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty ```

Comment: все заработало, я просто не обернул ваш пример в функцию и в хук. после того как добавил add_action('wp_head', 'custom_raw_output', 11). Мне только не понятно почему war_dump() не показал результатов, по идее он все равно должен был вывести какие-то данные. Итог:  ```add_action('wp_head', 'custom_raw_output', 11);
function custom_raw_output(){
    $products = wc_get_products(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'published',
    ) );
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($products); echo '</pre>';
}```

Comment: выволось в хедер потому что вы используете хук `wp_head`, не показывает war_dump() потому что нужно писать через v `var_dump()`